# All records are displaying on a single row when exporting array to a csv file

Tags: php, csv

I am pulling some data from an api then exporting it to an excel file.

Here's my code:

```
// api code for the request here
$jsondecode = json_decode($content);
// echo '<pre>';
// var_dump($jsondecode);

foreach( $jsondecode as $value ) {
    //if null, create blank field
    if ( ( !isset( $value ) ) || ( $value == "" ) ){
        $value = "\t";
    }
    //else, assign field value to our data
    else {
        $value = str_replace( '"' , '""' , $value );
        $value = '"' . $value . '"' . "\t";
    }
    //add this field value to our row
    $line .= $value;
}
//trim whitespace from each row
$data .= trim( $line ) . "\n";

//remove all carriage returns from the data
$data = str_replace( "\r" , "" , $data );

$file_name = 'excel_data';
//create a file and send to browser for user to download
header("Content-type: application/vnd.ms-excel");
header( "Content-disposition: filename=".$file_name.".xls");
print "$header\n$data";
exit;
```

As shown above, after pulling the data from the api, i pass it through the PHPExcel library so as to export it into an excel file but all that data exported displays in on a single row as shown below:

[image: Here is the screen shot of excel file which I am getting after running this script]

How can i have each of the record of data in that excel file display on a new line/row?

Comment: that is NOT a xls file. simply setting the content header does not magically change the contents. looking at the data a proper csv would be better

Comment: PHPExcel is a library for generating/manipulating ACTUAL .xls/xlsx files. All you've got is a bunch of CSV that you're **LYING** about being excel. Just because excel loads that doesn't mean it's really excel. And since you're stripping out the `\r` characters, it no longer has windows/dos line endings, and excel is being perfectly correct in thinking it's all one line - it is... it's a single line DOS file. you're building a unix text file.

Comment: Dagon and Marc.. i've seen multiple examples on the internet involving exporting arrays to excel using PHPExcel library. which is exactly what i'm doing above

Comment: no your not, there is no use of the PHPExcel library in the code above. FYI the Marc B above wrote the PHPExcel library

Comment: Lots of things on the internet aren't true. I'm not seeing PHPExcel being loaded or called to create a true Excel file.

Comment: @Dagon - Wrong Marc B, but the poster most certainly is __not__ using PHPExcel if that's their code, it's nothing more than badly-written homebrew tab-separated value, not even using the more appropriate PHP built-in fputcsv() function to write a sensible CSV file

Comment: @MarkBaker, doh sorry guys you all look the same to me ;-)

Comment: noted. apologies about the mixup

Comment: As an answer to your question, get rid of that bad homebrew and try using PHP's built-in [fputcsv()](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.fputcsv.php) function

Comment: that's what i needed all along Mark. Confused myself with the above 'homebrew' and PHPExcel library till i forgot to use the basics. thanks for pointing it out